# Where should I store my application files (data, cache, logs, crashes, etc.)

Tags: linux, directory, directory-structure, xdg, xdg-user-dirs

Although I did some research on this subject, I couldn't reach the exact information I wanted. Actually, not exactly disclosed, everyone approached in a different way.

For the: [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY)

I should store my files at:

- **Temp files:** `/var/temp/app_name/*` or `/temp/app_name/*`
- **Cache files:** `/var/cache/app_name/*`
- **Config files:** `~/.config/app_name/*`
- **Log files:** `/var/log/app_name/*`
- **Data files (database, etc.):** `???`

**Q1:** Is that the right approach for the recent systems?

For the `XDG` standart that [explained here](https://superuser.com/a/631984):

- **Temp files:** `???` or `/temp/app_name/*`
- **Cache files:** `~/.cache/app_name/*`
- **Config files:** `~/.config/app_name/*`
- **Log files:** `???`
- **Data files (database, etc.):** `???`

I cant understand why we store a cache file in the `~/.cache`. It doesn't make any sense to me because there was a built-in cache folder called `/var/cache`

In that case, I'm confused. Everywhere I investigate, there have been different approaches.

**Q2:** Where should we put the files (datas, logs, temps, configs, etc.) for a pure Linux distribution (which does not use $XDG) to create applications?

**Q3:** Some applications use the Linux structure, but some of use the `XDG` structure. How do they choose this? According to what situation? Do they use `$XDG` environment variables if we're using them?

According to the above situation, my `env | grep -i "XDG"` output:

```
XDG_VTNR=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=1
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/furkan/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_SEAT=seat0
```

**P.S:** *I don't know the parts I'm showing with* `???`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of your confusion may be the distinction between user applications and system applications.

So, for example, `apache` isn't run as an end user ("Harry" normally doesn't run Apache; it's run from a system startup script - systemd or init or however).  These sort of applications typically will follow the file system standard and store log files in `/var/log`, configuration files in `/etc` and so on.

Similarly, commands executed by the systems administrator as `root` designed to impact the whole machine (e.g. `apt` or `yum`) also follow the file system standard.

However, applications designed to be executed by the end user (e.g. a web browser and other desktop applications) follow the XDG standard.  Here "Harry" has his own personal cache, which is different to "Julie"; they visit different web sites, so have cached different pages.   Similarly, Harry may configure his desktop different to Julie, and so the configuration will be in the `~/.config` area.

Some locations (eg `/tmp`) are designed to be shared by all users, so even desktop apps can use them... but even here a more modern `/run/user/` structure is sometimes used.

Comment: So, in that case, i should follow the XDG standart. :) Because the end user will use the software. Thank you!